# SAML for SharePoint 2010 Authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, saml

Is it possible to authenticate a user in SharePoint 2010 using a SAML Token provided by third-party?

Most of the examples of SSO configuration for SP2010 assume that you are going to use Active Directory as your user repository.  I do not want to setup ADFS, since all of my users are actually out on a SAML compatible Jasig CAS server.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to implement a custom authentication provider to make this work without ADFS. See http://www.rightpointconsulting.com/community/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2010/09/02/configuring-custom-providers-using-sharepoint-2010-claims-based-authentication.aspx

Comment: That post has nice information, but isn't really showing how to integrate with some standard SAML SSO, as he is building an STS that still uses the some MembershipProvider implementation.